# Top level folders show permissions inherited from Parent Object - who's the Parent?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, domain

Looking at a Windows 2012 R2 server that has `D:\Users`, `D:\Admin`, `D:\Repository` and a few more like that that are shared.

When looking at security, they show inheriting permissions from Parent Object.

Seems to me that would be `D:\` and that would show inheriting from `D:\`

What is the Parent Object then for these folders? They aren't sub-folders of anything.

If I create a new folder, shows as I'd expect before any tweaking inheriting from `D:\` - no Parent Object.

The owner for these existing folders are Administrators (DOMAIN-NAME\Administrators).

Sorry if this is a total duh question, but I haven't really seen that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way that this can be caused (though I can't say not this is exactly the cause of what you're seeing) is by [moving directories in the volume after they've had permissions applied from a parent object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/inherited-permissions-not-automatically-update). Object permissions are added at time of creation, and though it appears that Microsoft has "changed the rules" on this a little bit over time (see my comments below) I suspect there are still sharp edge-cases in the code where this holds true.

It looks like Windows Server 2012 tries much harder than prior versions of Windows to "correct" for this behavior. Here's instructions to reproduce the behavior in Windows Server 2008, though:

- Make a folder "D:\Test"
- Edit the NTFS permission and add "Guests / Full Control" to the "D:\Test" folder
- Make a child folder "D:\Test\Test-Child"
- From an elevated command prompt, execute `move D:\Test\Test-Child D:\`.

When you examine the permissions of the "D:\Test-Child" folder you'll see "Guests / Full Control" being inherited from the "Parent Object".

I can't repro this on Windows Server 2012, which tells me that Microsoft has added some code to cover this particular edge case.

Raymond Chen [posted about this behavior on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/24/717181.aspx) back in 2006. I [commented on this, saying that it was a design flaw](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/24/717181.aspx#724976). I find it interesting that, years later, somebody else at Microsoft agreed and changed the behavior.

Comment: This makes sense and I reproduced this on Server 2012 R2. If you move subfolders after permissions or ownership has been changed outside the folder where it was created, the Parent inheritance shows, leaving you clueless as to what this Parent might have once been.